# Core Data Managed Context not saving in multi-threaded environment

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, core-data

While trying to learn more about Core Data and multithreading, I wrote an app that fails to save to core data.   First some
background.  Before my view appears, I create managed context.  This happens in
the main thread:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (!self.managedObjectContext) [self useDocument];

}

- (void)useDocument
{
    NSURL *url = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
    url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:MY_DOCUMENT];
    UIManagedDocument *document = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:url];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]) {
        [document saveToURL:url
           forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
          completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
              if (success) {
                  NSLog(@"@@@AMRO--->managedObjectContext has been setup");
                  self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
                  [self refresh];
              }
          }];
    } else if (document.documentState == UIDocumentStateClosed) {
        [document openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
            if (success) {
                NSLog(@"@@@AMRO--->managedObjectContext has been opened");
                self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
                [self refresh];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"@@@AMRO--->managedObjectContext has been set");
        self.managedObjectContext = document.managedObjectContext;
    }
}
```

When my view appears, I fetch data from a client using this approach.  The
reason I do this is because I do not want my view to be blocked as my client
refresh is happening:

```
        dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Client Fetch", NULL);
        dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
            [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
               dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self reload];
                    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
                        [self refreshClientInformation];
                    });
                });
            }];
        });
```

The call to `refreshClientInformation`, takes about 2 minutes to retrieve
information, however, I want the view to load in the meantime with whatever I
have.  The above approach prevents me
from being able to save to context despite the explicit call to
`[self.managedContext save:&error]` in refreshClientInformation
after each client data update.  `refreshPersonalClientInformations` executes in the "Client Fetch" thread queue.

```
- (void) refreshPersonalClientInformation
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"CLIENT"];
    request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"stationId" ascending:YES]];
    NSDate *twoHoursAgo = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-2*60*60];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"conditionsUpdated < %@", twoHoursAgo];
    NSError *error = nil;

    int counter = 0;

    // Execute the fetch
    NSArray *matches = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

    // Check what happened in the fetch
    if (!matches) {  // nil means fetch failed;
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Fetch failed to find CLIENT %@ in database", DEFAULT);
    } else if (![matches count]) { // none found, so lets retrieve it below
        return;
    } else {
        for (CLIENT *client in matches) {
            NSDictionary *clientDict = [ClientFetcher clientInfo:client.clientId];

            client.name = [clientDict[NAME] description];

            client.age = [clientDict[AGE] description];
            client.updated = [NSDate date];
            if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@AMRO Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }

            //Have to rate limit requests at no more than 10 per minute.
            NSLog(@"Sleeping for 6s");
            sleep(6);
            NSLog(@"Done sleeping for 6s");
        }
    }
}
```

I even tried to run the save in refreshPersonalClientInfo by doing this:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
 });
```

But that did not work, no errors were detected

As an experiment I changed the thread call to this when my view appears and my
core data eventually gets saved, the problem is that my view is blocked and I have to
wait a long time while the data is getting retrieved.  Also when I say eventually, I mean that it does not happen after I call `[self.managedContext save:nil]`, but after a few minutes:

```
        dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Client Fetch", NULL);
        dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
            [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                [self refreshPersonalClientInformation];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self reload];
                });
            }];
        });
```

Any suggestions on how I should retrieve my informaion in a background thread
and be able to save the data to disk while I still leave my UI accessible?

Comment: Look here, http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/

Comment: As Aaron said you should make "child context to perform everything in the background" as Apple recommends "a single ManagedObjectContext should not be shared with multiple threads".

Comment: When you open the UIManagedDocument the open or save is performed asynchronously so you need to make sure you don't try using the managedObjectContext before the completion handler gets called. Check out this link for more detail on waiting for background activities to complete before enabling the UI. In the example it's dealing with background imports from iCloud so much the same as your use case. http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/uimanageddocument-icloud-integration/when-to-enable-the-user-interface/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're better to create a child context to perform everything in the background:

```
dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Client Fetch", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        context.parentContext = self.managedObjectContext;
        [context performBlock:^{
            [self refreshPersonalClientInformation];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self reload];
            });
         }];
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a shot.  I should read up on the child/parent context to understand the principal behind this.

Comment: I resisted doing the child/parent context for ages myself actually, but now I have my head around it, I actually use it every day, and have had a much nicer core-data experience because of it!

Comment: @Aaron parent/child context was really buggy, especially in multithread environment. So your resistance was instead good programmer behavior :-) But maybe things has probably been fixed with current iOS release (7), so I need to give another chance myself too :-)

Comment: @Leonardo you're right, it was actually pretty bad, but works really nice now, definitely worth your time to take a look :)

Comment: I tried the approach you suggested btw, and it did not seem to work form me.  The code snippet you suggested allowed the view to come up, but whatever I had in terms of data did not load till the other thread finished pulling the data.  That is fine, however, I did not see evidence of it saving.  I plan to read up more on child context first to wrap my head around this as it seems to be the consensus amongst other responders as the path I should go down.

Comment: @retro I read up  cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata and what I gather is I need to create an MOC in my useDocument() function.  Then I would utilize a child context when I spawn a thread.  Is this correct.

Comment: You could do this, yes.

Comment: @Aaron, sorry it took so long to get back to you.  I needed time to understand cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata.  They create a NSURLDocument differently than what I did, so I used their approach first and tied my parent and child contexts to it.  I use the child context for all the fetching and the parent one for the writing.  I also registered for did and willSave notifications so I can merge my contexts.  It seems to work, but its quite a complex approach.  I cannot purport that I understand all the code completely.  I hope to simplify the code more for my immediate need.

Comment: If you want to edit your question and supply to complex code I'm happy to take a look!